# What is the meaning of fwd-i-search: _ and why does it appear in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

As stated, I had just run a pretty long program, it finished, usual prompt shows up in the terminal (PS C:\Users\…\program_name) and then a few minutes later, `fwd-i-search: _` appears in the next line. I can type next to it and it changes to `failed-fwd-i-search` when I do. Can’t seem to execute any more programs and need to restart the IDE to get it to disappear. I’m just wondering what this command does and why it would spontaneously show up?

I have tried Googling to no avail. The phrase "forward search" comes up a lot in Google results, but refers to Linux systems which I’m not running. This is the second time the issue has come up in 6 months, so it is infrequent but I am wondering what the cause could be.

I'm using PowerShell in VS Code for what it's worth.

Comment: I googled it and it looks like it's not just *Nix shells, PowerShell can do it to. Here's [a random example I found](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/2130). I bet it behaves the same as *Nix shells, so try pressing Esc to exit search mode. And I bet you accidentally pressed Ctrl+S to start it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, will try esc next time. Laptop was pretty far away from me when it happened so I’m sure I didn’t accidentally hit anything. Unsure about PSReadLine, I’ll take a look. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've installed [the PSReadline module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSReadLine), or you're using [the PowerShell extension](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell) for VS Code (which bundles PSReadLine (see also its `powershell.integratedConsole.useLegacyReadLine` [setting](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/main/package.json#L912))), that's probably why. This is a history searching feature. It allows you to search for commands that you've previously run and re-run them (the more commonly used command is *reverse search*). You can find related docs about what `reverse-search-history` and `forward-search-history` mean in [the GNU Readline docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html). In Readline, you are always at a "line" in the history, and can navigate between history lines using various commands and their keyboard bindings.

[Related keybinding code in PSReadline](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/33b74db80d142df7ba3b1302cc4919b5caaf9c76/PSReadLine/KeyBindings.cs#L209) in the `SetDefaultWindowsBindings` function:

```cs
{ Keys.CtrlS,                  MakeKeyHandler(ForwardSearchHistory,      "ForwardSearchHistory") },
```

And [the related prompt string definition code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/33b74db80d142df7ba3b1302cc4919b5caaf9c76/PSReadLine/History.cs#L110) in the `PSConsoleReadLine` class:

```cs
private const string _forwardISearchPrompt = "fwd-i-search: ";
```

You can read more about PSReadline in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline and https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine.

You should be able to press <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit/close the search prompt. Keybindings for PSReadline can be configured using `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`. For more info, see [the readme](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine#usage).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like "control-S" command on Windows VS Code puts the terminal into this search mode. I normally save my code with the keyboard command often and subconsciously. It seems that VS Code will chage focus to the terminal while I am in the code editor and thus turn this mode on. This question helped figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue.  Google led me to this thread.

I tried escape, but that didn't work.  Looks like if you press "CTRL + C" it will break out.  "CTRL + S" definitely puts it into this mode.

Answer (score 0):

Its appearing when you are using CTRL+S in the terminal, you can get out from that mode using CTRL+C in terminal too. It allows you to search for commands that you've previously run and re-run them (the more commonly used command is reverse search).
I also searched and found that it can appear when you are running code using F8. I often encounter this problem when I want to save code, but accidentally do it in the terminal